# How is this Calculation working?

Tags: c++, timer, linux-kernel, arm, arm64

I have come across this piece of code where nanoseconds since the epoc and since boot has been calculated but I didn't get how?

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/cloudius-systems/osv/arch/aarch64/arm-clock.cc#61

```
 s64 arm_clock::uptime()  
{
    u64 cntvct;
    asm volatile ("isb; mrs %0, cntvct_el0; isb; " : "=r"(cntvct) :: "memory");

    cntvct = ((__uint128_t)cntvct * NANO_PER_SEC) / this->freq_hz;
    return cntvct; 
}
```

CNTVCT is cyclic counter register, why is the value of this register divided by CPU frequency and then multiplied by NANO_PER_SEC?

Also, how can Time of day be derived from these nanoseconds?

Comment: Clearly, you boot the machine _at_ the epoch and never let it run for more than an hour or so ;) Is there any evidence that that code is actually fully functional? (the `::time()` and `::boot_time()` implementations in particular look like a horrible hack to just get some basic functionality up and running)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is the value of this register divided by CPU frequency and then
>   multiplied by NANO_PER_SEC?

It is to convert units

**CNTVCT** is incremented each clock cycle

**Frequency** is clock cycles per second

**NANO_PER_SEC** is nanoseconds per second

so looking at the units of:

```
CNTVCT * NANO_PER_SEC
-------------
frequency
```

they are:

```
clocks * nano/sec
------------------------
clocks/sec
```

equals (multiplying numerator and denominator by `sec`)

```
clocks * nano
-------------
clocks
```

equals (dividing numerator and denominator by `clocks`)

```
nano
```

so you need to divide by frequency to get seconds and multiply by nano to make it nano seconds

> Also, how can Time of day be derived from these nanoseconds?

the nanoseconds is since boot time, not the epoch

But, you can get the current time of day, subtract the current nanoseconds, and then adjust by the nanoseconds going forward

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.  You said Frequency is clock cycles per nanosecond but substituted it to clock/sec, isn't it should be clock/nanosecond? Also what I understood from your answer , CNTVCT is incremented every nanoseconds hence result should be nanoseconds, right?

Comment: edited to correct that typo, frequency is per second

Comment: Also, is it Ok to say CVTVCT is incremented every second and why author of code wanted to have resolution in nanoseconds why not just milliseconds  ?

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar CVTVCT is **NOT** incremented every second, it **is** incremented every clock cycle.  And you would need to contact the author to discover his motivation

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Does CNTVCT consistent across processor cores? My environment is Rpi4, and I didn't find any statement states that it does. What I knew is that CNTVCT is a percpu register. Thanks!